# Docker-compose can't connect via socks-proxy to SSH remote host

Tags: ssh, docker, proxy, docker-compose, socks

I'm trying to deploy containers using `docker-compose` to remote server via SSH. Remote server SSH can be accessed only via SOCKS proxy. I created `~/.ssh/config` with valid SOCKS configuration for that:

```
Host <my.host>
  HostName <my.host>
  ProxyCommand socks-connect -S <socks-user>@<socks-host>:<socks-port> %h %p
  Port <ssh-port>
  User <ssh-user>
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<ssh-key>
```

This config is working fine: I can connect via proxy using `ssh <my.host>` command.

Then I created Docker context, and tested it:

```sh
$ docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://<my.host>"
$ docker --context=remote ps
<list of running containers on remote host>
```

But when I try to use this context with `docker-compose`, it fails with error:

```sh
$ docker-compose --context=remote --verbose ps
ERROR: Got error response from SOCKS server: 4 (Host unreachable)
FATAL: failed to begin relaying via SOCKS
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Also, I tried using `DOCKER_HOST` environment but got the same error: `env DOCKER_HOST="ssh://<my-host>" docker-compose ps`.

So it seems the problem is in `docker-compose` because pure `docker` commands works correctly. What could be the problem here and how can I fix this behavior?

Docker client version: `20.10.7`
Docker server version (remote): `19.03.12`
Docker compose version: `1.29.2`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ssh method did not check ~/.ssh/config, there is another way by forward remote docker sock to local tcp port:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_using-an-ssh-tunnel-to-connect-to-a-remote-docker-host

```
ssh -NL localhost:23750:/var/run/docker.sock user@hostname
```

Then:

```
DOCKER_HOST="tcp://localhost:23750" docker-compose build
```